# Is there a better way to get data from localStorage after storing the data without refreshing/reloading the page

Tags: json, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope, local-storage

I'm trying to make a button that could store the data to the localStorage. After storing the data, I want to get the data without refreshing/reloading the page

The way I use to fix this case is, I put 2 commands on a button. The first command is to store the data, and the second command is to get the data using $scope to make it easy to display it on the page

Here is my code

```
$scope.storeData = function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('value') === null){
        // The value that will set to the localStorage
        $scope.data = 'Selamat sore';
        
        // To set the value on $scope.data to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('value', JSON.stringify($scope.data));
        
        //To get the value and display it on the page
        $scope.getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('value'));
    }else{
        $scope.getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('value'));
    }
}
```

It's actually working, but maybe there is a better way to do this

Thanks

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Take a look at [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage). Keeps a reference to your data

Answer (score 0):

I find this cleaner, and simpler.

```
function MyController($scope) {
  // if value is null a default 'Selamat sore' is set
  $scope.data = localStorage.getItem('value') || 'Selamat sore';
  
  $scope.saveData = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('value', JSON.stringify($scope.data));
  }
}
```